# Run android instrumentation test without ADB?

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, android-instrumentation

Is there anyway to run android instrumentation test without using ADB? For example, click on a button in the APP's settings page and start some UI automation test programmatically. currently it can be done by `adb shell am instrument`.

Comment: As far as I know there is not. Various examples use [adb/Android Studios](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/03/10/android-test-script/). Why can't you use adb?